# useEffect is not removing events correctly

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing a problem there is `<App/>` component which renders a child i.e. `<Button/>` component.
 The `<Button/>` component has 2 `props` one is a boolean value and the other is function. A backdrop will show when the user clicks the button, backdrop is just a `div` that hides on the user click.

When the boolean prop is changed, the `<Button/>` component dynamically adds the event listeners and removes the listeners when the user clicks anywhere on the document.

I successfully added this functionality with class-based lifecycle hooks but facing a problem when replacing the  component with React hooks.

I know there is a hook named `useEffect` which can replace the behavior of `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidUpdate` but my implementation of `useEffect` is not removing listeners based on the prop changed. Even when the backdrop is hidden, listeners are working without clicking a button and why the linter is complaining.

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'addEvents' and
>   'removeEvents'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.
>   (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps).

How can I fix this behavior and make this component like a class `<Button />` component?

**Functionality with class component:**

```js
// CSS styles for backdrop
const customStyles = {
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
  position: "absolute",
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0
};

// Button class component
class Button extends React.Component {
  // Return the function
  toggle = event => {
    return this.props.toggle(event);
  };

  // Attach Listener to the document object
  handleDocumentClick = event => {
    this.toggle(event);
  };

  // Add listeners to the document object
  addEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      // Event propogate from body(root) element to eventTriggered element.
      document.addEventListener(event, this.handleDocumentClick, true)
    );
  };

  // remove listeners from the document object
  removeEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.removeEventListener(event, this.handleDocumentClick, true)
    );
  };

  // Add or remove listeners when the prop changes
  manageProp = () => {
    if (this.props.open) {
      this.addEvents();
    } else {
      this.removeEvents();
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.manageProp();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    alert("Button cleanup");
    this.removeEvents();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.open !== prevProps.open) {
      this.manageProp();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.toggle}>Button</button>;
  }
}

// App class component
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  toggle = () => {
    alert("Button is clicked");
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        {/* Class-based Button Component */}
        <Button open={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggle} />
        {/* Backdrop */}
        {this.state.open && <div style={customStyles} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Component with react hook:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Button = props => {
  const toggle = event => {
    return props.toggle(event);
  };

  // Attach this to the document object
  const handleDocumentClick = event => {
    toggle(event);
  };

  // Add event listeners
  const addEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.addEventListener(event, handleDocumentClick, true)
    );
  };

  // Remove event listeners
  const removeEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.removeEventListener(event, handleDocumentClick, true)
    );
  };

  // Add or remove listeners based on the state changes
  const manageProp = () => {
    if (props.open) {
      addEvents();
    } else {
      removeEvents();
    }
  };

  // Mount, Unmount & DidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    manageProp();
    // Unmount
    return () => {
      alert("Button cleanup");
      removeEvents();
    };
  }, [props.open]);

  // Render it
  return <button onClick={toggle}>Button</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/d1-d10nl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returned from `useEffect` every time any of the dependencies change. In your case, that dependency is `props.open`.

When you call `removeEvents` from this function, you will add the events twice by virtue of `props.open` being true. Instead what you can do is to remove the event everytime the prop changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Add or remove listeners based on the state changes
    const manageProp = () => {
      if (props.open) {
        addEvents();
      } else {
        removeEvents();
      }
    };
    // mount
    manageProp();
    // unmount
    return () => {
      removeEvents();
    };
  }, [props.open]);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/d1-d3oj0)

Just move `addEvents` and `removeEvents` into the `useEffect` to get rid of the warning

Comment: Does `return () => { removeEvents(); };` will not execute when the component is unmount? I thought it will only work when the component is unmounted.

Comment: yes, it also executes when the component unmounts, that is also a change in prop

Comment: Thanks, Why linter is complaining `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'addEvents' and 'removeEvents'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.`

Comment: The linter looks for all variables used inside `useEffect`, it sees `addEvents` and `removeEvents` as two deps that could change and cause bugs for your application.  See an explanation in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). you can either move them inside `useEffect` or add them to deps array

Comment: What kind of bugs? Can you provide me a clean solution so I can learn?

Comment: The docs has dedicated page for [these](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) [functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little bit of clean up of your code, but the main point is you have to store `props.open` in a locally scoped constant before using it in your useEffect hook:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Button = props => {
  const isOpen = props.open;

  // Add event listeners
  const addEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.addEventListener(event, props.toggle, true)
    );
  };

  // Remove event listeners
  const removeEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.removeEventListener(event, props.toggle, true)
    );
  };

  // Mount, Unmount & DidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add or remove listeners based on the state changes
    const manageProp = () => {
      if (isOpen) {
        addEvents();
      } else {
        removeEvents();
      }
    };
    // mount
    manageProp();
    // unmount
    return manageProp;
  }, [isOpen]);

  // Render it
  return <button onClick={props.toggle}>Button</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

[Forked sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/d1-zxpru)
[And some reading for you here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#swimming-against-the-tide)